# How to activate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure " in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection

I don't see SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure  listed in the site features list. but If i try to enable "SharePoint Server Publishing" I get an error saying that the Infrastructure plug in must be activated first

any thoughts (error message below)

Site

> The feature being activated is a Site scoped feature which has a dependency on a Site Collection scoped feature which has not been
>   activated. Please activate the following feature before trying again:
>   SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure

Web

> The Site scoped feature being activated has a dependency on hidden Site scoped feature . Hidden features cannot be auto-activated across
>   scopes. There may be one or more visible Site scoped features that
>   auto-activate the dependent hidden feature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you should find "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" under

"Site settings" > "Site Collection Administration" > "Site collection features"

you wont find it under site feature

or you can access it through this link :

```
https://{sharepoint server}/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site
```

Answer (score 7):

Things are a little different on SharePoint Online (SPO) than on SharePoint Server. You find features in the Site Settings page (equal to server version). But in the SPO version, the *manage site feature* link is located in the section **Site Actions**. You can browse to it directly via the URL

```
https://<site collection url>/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx
```

Unfortunately, the name is different on the SPO version which may cause confusion. Activate SharePoint Server Publishing on your site, and you'll have expected functionality of the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to Site Settings->Site Administration->Site Collection Features-> SharePoint Server publishing site infrastructure

Check this link: It will help you understand what all it does

http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2011/06/23/sharepoint-publishing-features-functionality.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to go back to root site first.

then follow this navigation

**Site settings** -> **Site Collection Administration** -> **Site collection features**

activate

**SharePoint Server Publishing** feature

Answer (score 0):

You need to be an website collection administrator to perform that. If you are one you can go to **Site settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Site collection features** and **activate the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure"**.

If you as an website collection owner with full access you can go to site settings -> Manage site features but if you try to enable the "SharePoint Server Publishing" feature you might got an error (I assume the one you reference) that the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" isn´t running and that you aren´t allowed to enable it (see the [source](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/sharepoint/412-howto-create-an-enterprise-wiki-on-sharepoint-online.html) for more info's and some screenshots). As an owner you can only enable that on subsites if the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" is enabled on a per collection basis from an sharepoint site collection administrator.